# Qml not update button after model change

Tags: qml, qt5, models

Project and code here https://github.com/neochapay/radon

look on: 
pages/PlaylistPage.qml

in 21 line - call model and set played track. Go in to model:

src/model/playlistmodel.cpp

look on 80 line - like everything is right and everything is set. And go to

pages/PlayList/PlayListItem.qml

look at 85 line - result ask: why button not change?

Comment: add a minimal, working sample code here that shows your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have to emit the [`dataChanged` signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) in order to let the view know the model changed some of its data.

Comment: Ok i add signal https://github.com/neochapay/radon/blob/master/src/model/playlistmodel.cpp#L90  but button not change

Comment: Because you specify an invalid index, use [QAbstractListModel::index](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html#index) to get a valid one :
`emit dataChanged(index(idx), index(idx));`